# Cyclic dependency error when decorating using Ninject 3.0 conventional bindings

Tags: inversion-of-control, ninject, decorator, cyclic-reference

Please see the sample code below. Its an over simplified scenario to demonstrate a problem I am encountering when binding using the `WhenInjectedInto` method. This has always worked with the earlier version of ninject. But some how with this upgrade to 3.0 I can't see where is the problem. I am getting a cyclic dependency exception (i.e. the decorator is being injected into itself) when I shouldn't be getting that one if the `WhenInjectedInto` method gets applied properly.

Please also note, this is an oversimplified scenario, hence the classes and interfaces follow convention, so possibly for this code sample a solution can be achieved using default conventions with a lot less ioc code, but bare in mind for my actual scenario I won't have classes and interfaces follow conventions so fluently.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Ninject.Extensions.Conventions;
using Ninject.Extensions.Conventions.BindingGenerators;
using Ninject.Syntax;

namespace Ninject.Usage.Spike
{
public class ElderlyPerson : IPerson
{
    private readonly IPerson _actual;

    public ElderlyPerson(IPerson actual)
    {
        _actual = actual;
    }

    public string Name { get { return string.Format("Sir {0}", _actual.Name); } }
}

public class Person : IPerson
{
    public string Name { get; protected set; }
}

public interface IPerson { string Name { get; } }

[TestFixture]
public class Class1
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        using(var k = new StandardKernel())
        {
            k.Bind<IPerson>().To<ElderlyPerson>().InSingletonScope();
            k.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly()
                            .SelectAllClasses()
                            .Where(t => t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof (IPerson)))
                            .BindWith<MyGenerator>()
                            .Configure(c => c.WhenInjectedInto<ElderlyPerson>().InSingletonScope()));

            var person = k.Get<IPerson>();
            Assert.That(person.Name, Is.StringContaining("Sir"));
        }
    }
}

public class MyGenerator : IBindingGenerator
{
    public IEnumerable<IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object>> CreateBindings(Type type, IBindingRoot bindingRoot)
    {
        return type == typeof(ElderlyPerson) 
            ? Enumerable.Empty<IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object>>() 
            : new[] { bindingRoot.Bind(typeof(IPerson)).To(type) };
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Where` condition is wrong! You can't assign `IPerson` to `Person`. Switch the arguments.

Comment: Thanks Remo. Stupid error on my part in an attempt to simplify the problem domain.